# Post form to external Paypal window on Windows Phone with Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, windows-phone-8, paypal

This question is a continuation to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606200/phonegap-and-external-links-on-windows-phone-8).

I'm trying to post a form with information to Paypal. The application is currently built using Javascript and HTML5 on Cordova targeting Windows Phone 8.

I've managed to get regular external links to open using the InAppBrowser plugin provided by Cordova (so external links open in the native browser instead of inside the app). However, I can't seem to be able to post a form in the same way. I've gotten as far as being able to open the Sandbox Paypal URL in a separate window, but none of the information is being posted.

Here's a code snippet:

```
$(document).on("click", "#buyNow", function() {
    var form = document.forms[0];
    window.open(form.action, '_system', 'location=yes');
    form.submit();
});
```

where `form.action` is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

The above snippet is being offered as the solution, but I can only get as far as opening the action URL (which is the sandbox Paypal URL in my case), without any of the posted data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by removing the form element completely and inserting the parameters directly into the URL. I followed this guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

As an example, I rigged a button that detects an `onclick` event and opens a new window with the corresponding Paypal parameters.

```
$(document).on("click", "#buyNow", function() {
   window.open(form.action + "?cmd=_xclick&business=your_email_here@email.com&item_name=Test&item_number=1&amount=4&currency_code=EUR", '_system', 'location=yes');
});
```