# Integrate PayPal with Cordova without plugin?

Tags: cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins, paypal-sandbox

I read about the Paypal's plugin for Cordova/Phonegap 
https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-cordova-plugin-released/

But it seems that there is no support for Windows Phone, plus there is another gateway that must be supported by my application (it's a local gateway and I checked they released nothing for Cordova).

How can I do this integration without the plugins? Do I have to create a webpage and make the mobile access it via browser?! If so, how do I come back to my app when the work is finished?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a page on my server and using an iframe on my app. There is a button to close the iframe and I made it look like it is part of the app. Works great to me, and I didn't have to install or set up anything else

Comment: Is it an ionic application?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the link below for the Windows 8 Checkout SDK.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/gs_win8xo/

Plus link below is PayPal Mobile Overview for your reference.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mobile-overview/

Answer (score 0):

Suitably the links posted by PP_MTS_Steven, you can read:

> The PayPal Windows 8 SDK has been discontinued. There are no current
>   plans to remove API support for deployed applications, but if you are
>   developing a new integration, you should use another option such as a
>   web integration.

So I think the only solution now to use PayPal without plugins (except for iOS/Android where plugins exists) is the use of the InAppBrowser as done by this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990242/post-form-to-external-paypal-window-on-windows-phone-with-cordova).